# csv data split based on comma but ignore with double quotes or any brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse a .csv file in javascript and split the fields based on comma but it should ignore the commas within double quotes or any kind of brackets.
Here is the snippet of my data.

```
"263P", "12 KMS","http://www.someurl.com/color?width=10&height=70&iframe=true","[{"stop": "abc, def, A.B.C", "latlons": ["13.0455367265411", "77.5055545144687"]}]", "08:35,09:55,11:40", "13:00,  14:20,  15:40,  17:25"
```

I have tried many options which are suggested on stackoverflow but those are not working for my data.

one of the very near matching regex is

```
str.match(/(".*?"|[^,]+)(?=,|$)/g);
```

but it is not working properly within double quotes

Comment: one of the very near matching regex is str.match(/(".*?"|[^,]+)(?=,|$)/g); but it is not working properly within double quotes

Comment: What if you wrap your snippet in square brackets and use JSON.parse to turn it into an array.

Comment: The problem is this: `,"[{"stop"`. To get that working you'll have to be able to match all sorts of start & end brackets, because you're `"`s are not escaped

Comment: I assumed those "inner" quotes were escaped (and the escape is just not displayed in this question)

Comment: yes, @James, I wouldn't even know how to make sense of it otherwise; it seems as though it would be ambiguous.

Comment: You've got a show stopper there: _nested brackets_ which JS regex can't do recursively. Nothing you try will work. Use a language with PCRE engine.

Comment: yeah, it my mistake. Actually it's escaped.

Comment: mean while i came up with one regex str..match(/("\[.*?\]"|".*?"|[^",]+)(?=,|$)/g) which is working except last pair of quotes. i am getting only 13.00 instead of "13:00,  14:20,  15:40,  17:25"

Comment: Shashi, I'm waiting on you to try my suggestion.  The comments about regex not being suitable for this kind of thing are real.  `var thing = "[" + yourThing + "]";  var array = JSON.parse(thing);`

Answer (score 0):

i could form the regex for my own question so posting the solution here.

str.match(/("[.*?]"|".*?"|".*?"\r|[^",]+)(?=,|$)/g)

with this regex i am able to separate all the csv cells based on comma (ignoring within quotes).